# Why isn't the "low answer quality score" automatically flagged as helpful, when the answer is flagged as spam?

Tags: support, flags, helpful-flags

On *Drupal Answers*, an answer has been flagged as "low answer quality score" by the Community user; I flagged it as not an answer, and as spam.

As consequence, my "not an answer" flag has been automatically marked as helpful, but the automatic flag was not marked as helpful.

[image: screenshot]

Should not the automatic flag be marked as helpful, since the post has been deleted?

Comment: I'm guessing this is because the user who issued the flag = the user who dismissed the flag via deletion. Same thing happens if you dismiss your own VLQ flag with a close vote. I don't think Community will mind, though.

Comment: Damn you, community!